# Google/Analytics.h file not found error

Tags: ios, google-analytics

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AdMixerAdAdapter.h"
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>

@interface AdmobAdapter : AdMixerAdAdapter<GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate> {

    GADInterstitial * _interstitial;
    GADBannerView * _adView;
    GADRequestError * _error;

}

+ (void)registerTestDevices:(NSArray *)devices;

@end
```

This is the adMixerAdAdapter.h but when I compile it, Google/Analytics.h file not found

so I checked the Podfile.lock files.
'

```
PODS:
  - Google (1.3.2):
    - Google/Core (= 1.3.2)
  - Google/Analytics (1.3.2):
    - Google/Core
    - GoogleAnalytics (~> 3.12)
  - Google/Core (1.3.2):
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.1.0):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
  - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.3)
  - GoogleUtilities (1.1.0):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Google
  - Google/Analytics

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Google: 97618e118111b998cce1d8dd1bd98b82301d72db
  GoogleAnalytics: 9be1afdb8deeac4bb5f13ca7f7d3b9db2a1f43dc
  GoogleInterchangeUtilities: d7f7174176fbcf9710f696f1acebad4dbd98ac03
  GoogleNetworkingUtilities: 292992ab31b7b4ba32809a0e8b40e324cdfb2c0c
  GoogleSymbolUtilities: 82ad9f93d3615244b3f4ce440f5ab2515e8b4f56
  GoogleUtilities: 8ed9134debe11719097881711464752900668f10
```

COCOAPODS: 0.39.0'

It's some kinds of different from the normal one...

So I think it makes the error...

Can you help me solve the problem